# Rsyslog storing only certain type of events in a file

Tags: rsyslog, syslog, template

I am collecting TM Deepsecurity events on my syslog server.  The TM manager sends logs to my syslog server on port 514.  There are two types of events TM sends.  Deep Security Agent & Deep Security Manager logs.  I ran a tcpdump on my syslog server and able to see both types of events.  I have created a template under /etc/rsyslog.d/03.trendmicro.conf which will store the logs coming from TM IP's (listed as $fromhost-ip contains xxxxx) to a folder under /var/syslog/rsyslog.  I can see logs are getting stored under /var/syslog/rsyslog/TM-Server/ but I see only Deep Secuirty Manager logs.  Agents logs are not getting logged into a file.  I do not have any rules setup to exclude these events from going into a file.  Both these types of events come from same host.  How do I check why rsyslog is not storing them into a file ?